# Regular expression of a given language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Could somebody please confirm if a regular expression of language: 
$$ L := \{b(ab)^n a^m \mid n, m \geq 0\} $$ 
is
$$\{b, (ab)^* a^*\}? $$

And if not, could somebody please tell me why?

Comment: How is $\{b,(ab)^*a^*\}$ a regular expression?

Comment: Possibly related to/duplicate of [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54502/convert-a-right-linear-grammar-to-a-left-linear-grammar) and/or [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54509/drawing-automaton-for-right-linear-grammar).

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/). If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.

Answer (score 1):

In short, your answer is No. For explanation about **Regular language** and **Regular expression**, you can check [this link](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/reg-lang/definitions.html). And the correct answer to your question would be: $b(ab)^*a^*$